# Resample while keeping last date from input file (and not last day computed by `resample`)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

Using python pandas (but open to any other solution), I would like to up-sample a DataFrame, while keeping the *last date from my input file*. The default way of working of `DataFrame.resample` is to compute the *last day of the month*. Here is my example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> begin = pd.datetime(2013,1,1)
>>> end = pd.datetime(2013,2,20)
>>> dtrange = pd.date_range(begin, end, freq='5D')
>>> values = np.random.rand(len(dtrange))*10
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values}, index=dtrange)
>>> df
              values
2013-01-01  7.763089
2013-01-06  6.032173
2013-01-11  9.747979
2013-01-16  0.856741
2013-01-21  7.111047
2013-01-26  2.654279
2013-01-31  5.222770
2013-02-05  9.578846
2013-02-10  5.088311
2013-02-15  4.193273
2013-02-20  3.345553
>>> df.resample('M', how='last')
              values
2013-01-31  5.222770
2013-02-28  3.345553
```

The output that I expect is:

```
              values
2013-01-31  5.222770
2013-02-20  3.345553
```

Please note the date 2013-02-20. This is the true date from my input data, and not a date created by `resample`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not the most fancy way, but you can always `groupby` your time frequency and apply a custom function returning what you want.

A function to return the last value from the DataFrame:

```
my_resample = lambda x: x.sort_index().tail(1)
```

Then groupby the month frequency and apply the function:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'), group_keys=False).apply(my_resample)
```

Which results in:

```
              values
2013-01-31  5.167121
2013-02-20  4.829109
```

Comment: Not the most fancy way as you said, but this works, so I accept the answer.